# Can someone please help me identify this tree?

Tags: trees, berries, olive

[image]

Contains no white substance in twigs or leaves. Flowers are small and come out in clusters.

Comment: What area of the world is this growing in?are those dark purple pods seeds?

Comment: It's in south africa but we think it might have been imported. The fruit is dark purple inside with sticky white milky substance. But the twigs and leaves don't have the milky substance.

Comment: I suggest you photograph the fruit carefully and then search in Google Images.